# Write to a pointer address in C#

Tags: c#, pointers

Normally, I can write to a process using this:

```
WriteProcessMemory((int)processHandle, 0x01C0FE40, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesWritten);
```

But now I have address that looks like this `"BlackOps.exe"+0208173C` which is also supposed to have an offset of `18`. How can I write to the address it points to? Is this even a pointer?

EDIT: The goal is to write a float to the target address. The above pointer points to the games time-scale variable, which will be changeable by the user using the program.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: ...what are you trying to do?

Comment: You'll need to find the base address of the executable. There are APIs for that. But since it's an .exe file it's possible that it lacks relocation information and gets loaded at the same address every time.

Comment: Note that using an int as handle won't work in a 64 bit process. In addition, it's recommended to use SafeHandles over raw handles nowadays.

Comment: eh gads...why would you want to do this in a managed application!

Comment: If you are trying to perform IPC between two processes on the same machine use [.NET's pipes classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762927(v=vs.110).aspx).  They run in Kernel mode and so quite fast; faster than WCF; and easier than `WriteProcessMemory`

Answer (score 0):

The built in Process and ProcessModule class can give you the base address of the module, then you just add the relative offset, de-reference it using a multi level pointer function called FindDMAAddy(), which uses ReadProcessMemory.  This will yield the address after de-referencing each pointer and adding the appropriate offsets.

Then you just use WriteProcessMemory() on the result.

```
public static IntPtr FindDMAAddy(IntPtr hProc, IntPtr ptr, int[] offsets)
{
    var buffer = new byte[IntPtr.Size];
    foreach (int i in offsets)
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, ptr, buffer, buffer.Length, out var read);

        ptr = (IntPtr.Size == 4)
        ? IntPtr.Add(new IntPtr(BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0)), i)
        : ptr = IntPtr.Add(new IntPtr(BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0)), i);
    }
    return ptr;
}

Process proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("BlackOps")[0];

IntPtr modBaseAddr = proc.MainModule.BaseAddress;

float newTimeScale = 1.0;

IntPtr timeScaleAddr = FindDMAAddy(proc.Handle, modBaseAddr + 0x208173c, new int[] { 0x18 });

WriteProcessMemory(hProc, timeScaleAddr, newTimeScale, 4, out _);
```

Make sure you run as administrator, use pinvoke to get access to native WinAPI functions and check the return values and Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() for error checking if required.